# Android: IOException BufferedInputStream is closed after download

Tags: android, inputstream, ioexception

I've some problems with InputStream after download an image. downloadImages method return an InputStream that i write in a file. But there is an exception in inputStreamToFile method: java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed. Here the codes:

**Download**

```
public static InputStream downloadImages(String imageUrl) {

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;

        String urlBase =  imageUrl;

        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "downloadImages(): url request: " + urlBase);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlBase);
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(SystemConstants.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
            httpConn.setReadTimeout(SystemConstants.SOCKET_CONNECTION);

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                return inputStream;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "downloadImages(): exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(httpConn != null) httpConn.disconnect();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**From IS to file**

```
public static void inputStreamToFile(InputStream is) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "inputStreamToFile() called");
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            // Check if media is mounted or storage is built-in, if so, try and use external cache dir
            // otherwise use internal cache dir

            final String cachePath =
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
                            !Utils.isExternalStorageRemovable() ?
                            Utils.getExternalCacheDir(App.getContext()).getPath() :
                            App.getContext().getCacheDir().getPath();
            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(cachePath + File.separator + "vr"));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "read called");
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "inputStreamToFile(): outputStream is not null");
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The inputstream will be closed when you close the HttpConnection in the first method.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! But... now where i close the connection?!

Comment: The easiest way would be to call inputStreamToFile inside of downloadImages instead of returning the inputStream. Another solution would be to have one method opening the HttpConnection and returning it and another method closing the HttpConnection. Then you could access the InputStream between these two methods. But error handling could be a bit messy.

Answer (score -3):

Put your logcat.Then only we can identify the errors,bugs,etc